# Primefaces toggleable panel expands but doesn't collapse: javascript error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to implement a simple collapsible panel using PrimeFaces 3.5 using the version of Mojarra that comes with JBoss AS 7.1.1 (2.1.7-jbossorg-1 is the reported version number).  I downloaded PrimeFaces from the PrimeFaces Maven repository.

What I'm seeing is that if the panel is initially collapsed, I can expand it once but never collapse it again.  Here is the code to produce this:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:panel toggleable="true" collapsed="true" header="Title of the panel">
    <h:outputText value="Some text in a panel" />
  </p:panel>
...
</h:form>
```

In the Safari error console, I see the following error appear when I click the panel's Expand button:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'bG.easing[this.easing](b0,this.options.duration*b0,0,1,this.options.duration)')
```

coming from line 21 of jquery.js.jsf, but the expand operation works.

If, on the other hand, I start with the panel expanded, I can never collapse it, and get the same error message in the error console when I click the Collapse button.

I checked that I get the same behavior when I copy the source from the Primefaces showcase, but it works in my browser when I execute it directly from their web site.  This makes me think it must be something that isn't right in my JBoss server, but I don't know where to look to find the problem.

Has anyone seen this before, and point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

**Update:** I noticed while writing this post that PF 3.5 is brand new, so I tried again with the previous version, 3.4.2.  I see the same result.

Comment: This looks like some collision in jQuery. Did you imported any jquery js files manually? Or some jQuery plug-ins?

Comment: @partlov: Thanks for the comment, but no, I haven't done any manual configuration of jquery, and have not (deliberately) imported anything that appears to use a different version of jquery.

Comment: It would be nice to see more of your xhtml, because the xhtml that you provided above is simply not enough. This may be caused by a resource issues of yours (specified in h:head) or the use of f:view contentType="text/html" around h:head, h:body, etc...; i don't ever wrap h:head and h:body with f:view contentType="text/html".